# outFile C++ not writing to output text

Tags: c++, format, fstream, file-io

Down below is my incomplete program. I am having problems with writing to a text file. For example I want to write the number of snow days to a text file, but nothing shows up in the textfile when I debug in VS 2010. It does display my info and name, but nothing else works. It wont write anything after that. its NOT writing to a text file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

const string INFORMATION = "College Class";
const string MY_NAME = "Tom Hangler";

int main(void)
{

    ofstream outFile;


    int numberOfSnowDays;
    int greatestSnowDay;
    int dayNumber;
    double amounttOfSnow;


    outFile.open("Ex1Out.txt");
    outFile << setw(51) << INFORMATION << endl << setw(48) << MY_NAME << endl;



    cout << "Please enter num of days it snowed: " << endl;
    cin >> numberOfSnowDays;
    outFile << setw(10) << "Number of days of snow is: " << setw(10) << numberOfSnowDays;     

    int index;
    //Problem 1 for-loop
    for (index = 0; index < numberOfSnowDays; index++)
    {   
        cout << "Enter day: " << endl;
        cin >> dayNumber;
        cout << "Enter amount of snow: " << endl;
        cin >> amountOfSnow;

    };

    return 0;   
}
```

here is what my output displays:
College Class (centered)
Tom Hangler   (centered)

If i try to write anything after this, Nothing is written ever to the output file. And the output text file IS in my VS project that contains my .cpp file. I added the text file to project.

Comment: Apart from INFORMATION and MY_NAME, the only thing you write to the file is "Number of days of snow is: " and the number you entered at `cin >> numberOfSnowDays`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [closing](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ofstream/close/) the stream at the end of the function, it looks like the data isn't getting flushed.

```
outFile.close();
```

Comment: idk if this helps any but in the output window, it does say "Cannot find or open the PDP file" 3 times for ntdll.dll, kernel132,dll and kernelBase.dd

Answer (score 0):

Your code compiles and works on gcc 4.4.5 (apart from typo in amounttOfSnow).

Is it possible that you are looking at an old Ex1Out.txt file ?
Its most likely created in the Release or Debug subdirectory in your project, not where the .cpp files are.

Comment: well I use debug to run this program. It keeps asking me if I want to "reload the" text file. It says its been modified outside the source editor. So idk whats going on. I tested it both ways by saying yes and no, But still no output is written no matter what I do. I checked the output text file in its directory, and same thing: only the header is there, no data is written. Idk what's preventing this text file to be written, I get no warnings or errors.

Answer (score 0):

in your for loop, you only collect the amount of snow, but you don't write it to the text file.

Do you want to do something like this?

```
...
for (index = 0; index < numberOfSnowDays; index++)
{   
    cout << "Enter day: " << endl;
    cin >> dayNumber;
    cout << "Enter amount of snow: " << endl;
    cin >> amountOfSnow;
    // next line is new:
    outFile << "Day#: "<< dayNumber << ", snow: "<< amountOfSnow<<endl;
};
outFile.close()
...
```

Comment: yes. But above the for loop, i am writing a line of "num of days of snow" and it doesnt write that. and even with this change, my text file is not being written. I think it has something to do with vs IDk

Comment: ok this works. The data is written only when I end the debugging. Does that sound right? I also ran VS as admin this time.

Comment: yes, the debugger may interfere with flushing.

does it work outside the debugger?