# simple logic for loop C++

Tags: c++, c, if-statement, for-loop, logic

I am trying to write simple program using ONLY `for` loop (`if then` statement is allowed i think) And I am having trouble getting the highest snow date "calculated" from a bunch of user inputs.

This program writes user input amount of snow that fell on a number of days to a text file. I am supposed to also list the highest snow amount that fell, but *don't* (?) know how to do it in the `for` loop.

```
for (dayNumber = 1; dayNumber <= numOfSnowDays; dayNumber++)
    {   
        mostSnowDay = dayNumber;
        cout << "Day number:  " << dayNumber << endl;
        cout << "Enter amount of snow: " << endl;
        cin >> amtOfSnow;
        totalSnow = totalSnow + amtOfSnow;
        outFile << setfill(' ') << setw(15) << dayNumber << setw(25) << setprecision(2)   << amtOfSnow << endl;

        if ( dayNumber == 1 )
        {
            mostSnowDay = dayNumber;                             
        }
        else if ( amtOfSnow < mostSnowDay )
        { 
              //dont know what to put here or even if this is right. 
        }

    };
```

Comment: check my edit, I think you missed "don't" there.... Kindof reverses the meaning of the sentence:)

Comment: snow seems to be a popular homework topic today :-)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9181299/outfile-c-now-writing-to-output-text/9182491

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need some extra variables there:

```
 if ( dayNumber == 1 )
 {
     mostSnowDay = dayNumber;   // default - most amount of snow in first day  
     mostAmtOfSnow = amtOfSnow; // 
 }
 else if ( amtOfSnow > mostAmtOfSnow ) //if subsequent day has more snow
 { 
     mostSnowDay = dayNumber;     //mark the day
     mostAmtOfSnow = amtOfSnow;   //change largest amount of snow
 }
```

EDIT: Credit to Dan F. Remove the `mostSnowDay = dayNumber;` instruction at the beginning of the loop, it will re-initialize your variable each time the loop enters.

Comment: He also needs to eliminate the `mostSnowDay = dayNumber;` line from the top of the foor loop.

Comment: @user1193717 yes. But do you want that? I don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start with two variables outside your for loop that keep track of the maxSnowfall and the maxSnowfallDate:

```
  int maxSnowfallDate;
  int maxSnowfall;
```

Once in the for loop, you generally will test to see if a new max day has been achieved, and if so, you need to record the new max and the date of the new max.

```
  if( curSnowfall >  maxSnowfall ) {
    maxSnowfall = curSnowfall;
    maxSnowfallDate = dayNumber;
  }
```

It is common to just initialize the maxSnowfall to 0 outside the for loop and test each time, but it sounds like the assignment was to use a technique that didn't assign initially to an arbitrary (in this case 0) value. Instead, you just assign on the first run through the loop, then test for a new max on each subsequent run through the loop.

```
if( dayNumber == 1 ) {
  maxSnowfallDate = dayNumber;
  maxSnowfall = curSnowfall;
} else {
  if( curSnowfall > maxSnowfall ) {
    maxSnowfall = curSnowfall;
    maxSnowfallDate = dayNumber;
  } 
}
```